# ¿Cómo reemplazar siglas de una columna por números en una nueva columna?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un dataframe con una columna de dirección de viento en cuadrantes (por ejemplo N, NE, NW, etc) y necesito traducirlo en números en la columna de al lado (como dirección de viento en grados de acuerdo a N=360, NE= 45, NW=315, esa columna esta vacía originalmente). ejemplo:

| Viento_cuad | Viento_grados |
| --- | --- |
| SW | NA |
| NW | NA |
| N | NA |

estoy intentando el siguiente codigo:

```
METEO <- METEO %>% mutate(`Dirº`=str_replace(Dir_cuad, "NW", "315"))
```

```
METEO <- METEO %>% mutate(`Dirº`=str_replace(Dir_cuad, "N", "360"))
```

y obtengo esto:

| Viento_cuad | Viento_grados |
| --- | --- |
| SW | SW |
| NW | 360W |
| N | 360 |

es decir que hago una linea de código para cada cuadrante y valor asociado a ese cuadrante pero claramente no funciona. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el asunto es la columna que estas seleccionado al momento de ejecutar `str_replace()`. Una opción de lograr lo que buscar es hacer lo siguiente:

```
METEO %>% 
  mutate(`Dir°` = case_when(
    Viento_cuad == "NW" ~ "315",
    Viento_cuad == "N" ~ "360",
    # Acá puedes agregar otras direcciones como por ejemplo:
    # Viento_cuad == "S" ~ "XXX",
    TRUE ~ Viento_cuad
  ))
```

**Resultado:**

```
  Viento_cuad Dirº 
1          SW  SW 
2          NW 315
3           N 360
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más simple es armando previamente un vector con nombre y valor:

```
grados <- c(N = 0, NE = 45, E = 90, SE = 135, S = 180, SW = 225, W = 270, NW = 315)

METEO %>%
  mutate(`Dirº` = grados[`Dirº`])
```

Si respetas los nombres que hay en el dataframe, el vector `grados` funciona como vector de reemplazo de `nombre` x `valor`